# How to separate mp3, mp4 file name from string using php?

Tags: php, string

Hi anyone can help I want separate mp3, mp4 from imploded data in PHP

my data string

```
$data = "song1.mp3, video1.mp4, song2.mp3"
```

i want to divide into two separate strings 1 string contains only `mp4` with (`,`) separated and another with `mp3`

my data from database:

```
$data = "song1.mp3, video.mp4, song2.mp3";
$mp4 = video1.mp4,video2.mp4,..etc;
$mp3 = song1.mp3,song2.mp3,..etc;
```

thank you

Comment: You should post the code you already have. And maybe you should do what you want before you `implode` your data (check the extension, add to specific array)

Comment: to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your songs names are well formatted, meaning that they are named as `title.suffix`

```
<?php
     $data = "song1.mp3, video.mp4, song2.mp3";
     $mp3 = [];
     $mp4 = [];

     $song_names = explode(',', $data);
     foreach ($song_names as $song_name) {
         $song_name = trim($song_name);
         $parts = explode('.', $song_name);
         if (count($parts) == 2) {
             $suffix = $parts[1];
             if ($suffix == 'mp3') {
                 $mp3[] = $song_name;
             } else if ($suffix == 'mp4') {
                 $mp4[] = $song_name;
             }
         }
     }

     //using implode so that we won't have an extra comma hanging in the end
     $mp4 = implode(', ', $mp4);
     $mp3 = implode(', ', $mp3);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode()` to converting string to array by `,` delimiter. Then loop through array items and get extension of file name using `substr()` and check it.

```
$data = "song1.mp3, video1.mp4, song2.mp3";
$mp4 = $mp3 = "";
foreach (explode(",", $data) as $file){
    $file = trim($file);
    substr($file, -3) == "mp4" ? $mp4.=$file."," : $mp3.=$file.",";  
}
$mp4 = substr($mp4, 0, -1);
$mp3 = substr($mp3, 0, -1);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/A3PTn)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for a `preg_match_all()` regex:

```
<?php

$string = 'song1.mp3, video.mp4, song2.mp3';

$regex = '#([^,\s]+\.mp3)#';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $mp3s);

$regex = '#([^,\s]+\.mp4)#';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $mp4s);

var_dump($mp3s[0]);
var_dump($mp4s[0]);
```

Which gives you:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "song1.mp3" [1]=> string(9) "song2.mp3" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "video.mp4" }
```

Here's the code in action https://3v4l.org/2EmkR

Here's the docs for `preg_match_all()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: `\w+` does not support all allowed character in file name

Comment: it does in his example string. Of course if he has any other cases where it doesn't work, that's easy enough to tweak, but all examples given match.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - a slightly different approach using `pathinfo`

```
$data = 'song1.mp3, video1.mp4, song2.mp3';
$mp3s = [];
$mp4s = [];

foreach (explode(', ', $data) as $file) {
    $type = pathinfo($file)['extension'];
    $type === 'mp3' ? $mp3s[] = $file : $mp4s[] = $file;
}

echo implode(', ', $mp4s) . PHP_EOL;
echo implode(', ', $mp3s) . PHP_EOL;
```

Could definitely use some validation and so forth but as an MVP it does the trick.